# Tengo problemas a la hora de construir un proyecto en android studio. Al parecer tengo problemas con el plugin de gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

A continuacion dejo en pantalla el error que sale cuando presiono el botón de sync proyect with gradle files:

```
Build file 'C:\Armando\MyApplication\build.gradle.kts' line: 7
    
    Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.4', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
    
    * Try:
    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.4', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
    
    - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
    - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.1.4')
      Searched in the following repositories:
        Google
        MavenRepo
        Gradle Central Plugin Repository
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:237)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$resolvePluginRequests$3(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:167)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:212)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
```

Aquí dejo una imagen del editor, del directorio de carpetas y archivos y del error que me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito ayuda porque me es de vital importancia compilar las aplicaciones en android studio y no puedo. Alguien que sepa algo al respecto ? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando la versión '8.1.4' del plugin Gradle, debes cambiar la versión de Java, cambia a Jetbrains Runtime version 17.

ve a `File` > `Project Structure`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La versión del plugin Gradle esta relacionada con la version de Java usada en tu proyecto.